# R:poner etiquetas en un mapa

Tags: r

Me gustaría esbozar en mapa de españa en R y añadirle unos puntos en unas coordenadas determinadas que tengo en un archivo CSV;

como estas:

```
        Aranjuez<-39.595520, -3.391830
        San Martin de la vega<- 40.225155-3.530613
        Ruta de las vegas<- 40.320294-3.205903
        Mondejar<- 40.345348-3.137145
```

¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

He intentado con estos scripts de otro foro y no consigo hacerlo.

Cuando ejecuto el código map.unizar obtengo este error:

```
      Error in if (lon < -180 || lon > 180) { : 
      missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Script:
ubico mi alma mater

```
        unizar <- geocode('Universidad de Zaragoza, Zaragoza, España')
```

obtengo un mapa

```
        map.unizar <- get_map( location = as.numeric(unizar),
                   color = "color",
                   maptype = "roadmap",
                   scale = 2,
                   zoom = 16)
```

lo represento

```
        ggmap(map.unizar)
```

le añado puntos

```
        ggmap(map.unizar) + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat),
                           data = unizar, colour = 'red',
                           size = 4)
```

Gracias de antemano
Un coordial saludo

Comment: Adrian, que problema tienes con este script? algún error? Saludos

Comment: Si, cuando ejecuto el código map.unizar obtengo este error:
Error in if (lon < -180 || lon > 180) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tienes es en realidad que no logras obtener la latitud y longitud, veamos:

```
address <- 'Universidad de Zaragoza, Zaragoza, España'
unizar <- geocode(address)
```

Esto en consola arroja el siguiente mensaje

> Information from URL :
>   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Universidad%20de%20Zaragoza,%20Zaragoza,%20Espa%F1a&sensor=false
>   Warning messages: 1: In readLines(connect, warn = FALSE) :   cannot
>   open URL
>   'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Universidad%20de%20Zaragoza,%20Zaragoza,%20Espa%F1a&sensor=false':
>   HTTP status was '400 Bad Request' 2: In geocode(address) :
>       geocoding failed for "Universidad de Zaragoza, Zaragoza, España".   if accompanied by 500 Internal Server Error with using dsk, try
>   google.

Si vamos directamente al enlace (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Universidad%20de%20Zaragoza,%20Zaragoza,%20Espa%F1a&sensor=false) por medio de un navegador obtendremos un error más descriptivo:

```
{
   "error_message" : "Invalid request. One of the input parameters contains a non-UTF-8 string.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

Es decir no esta bien codificada la dirección que queremos buscar, ciertos caracteres (seguramente la ñ) no tiene un código `utf-8` adecuado. Para solucionarlo podemos hacer uso de [`enc2utf8()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Encoding.html):

```
address <- enc2utf8('Universidad de Zaragoza, Zaragoza, España')
```

y ahora sí, todo lo que sigue:

```
unizar <- geocode(address)
if (!any(is.na(unizar))) {
    map.unizar <- get_map( location = as.numeric(unizar),
                           color = "color",
                           maptype = "roadmap",
                           scale = 2,
                           zoom = 16)

    ggmap(map.unizar) + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat),
                                   data = unizar, colour = 'red',
                                   size = 4)
} else {
    stop("No hemos podido recuperar la coordenadas")
}
```

Le agregué un control para saber si hemos podido recuperar correctamente latitud y longitud, Google puede "banearte" en algún momento si haces muchas consultas y habría que controlarlo.

El resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo que quieres es el mapa completo de España puedes modificar el nivel de zoom, recuerda además que si ya tienes la latitud y la longitud, no necesitas llamar a `geocode()`:

```
puntos <- data.frame(lon=c(-3.391830, -3.530613, -3.205903, -3.137145, -0.9015065),
                     lat=c(39.595520, 40.225155, 40.320294, 40.345348, 41.64206),
                     nom=c('Aranjuez', 'San Martin de la vega', 'Ruta de las vegas', 
                           'Mondejar', 'Universidad de Zaragoza, Zaragoza, España')
)

map.unizar <- get_map( location = puntos[1,-3],
                       color = "color",
                       maptype = "roadmap",
                       scale = 2,
                       zoom = 6)

ggmap(map.unizar) + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat),
                               data = puntos, colour = 'red',
                               size = 2)
```

El Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si aún así el resultado no te convence, te sugiero que le eches una mirada a [**LeafLet**](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/), que te ofrece una visualización dinámica, muy configurable y atractiva:

```
library(leaflet)
library(magrittr)

puntos <- data.frame(lon=c(-3.391830, -3.530613, -3.205903, -3.137145, -0.9015065),
                     lat=c(39.595520, 40.225155, 40.320294, 40.345348, 41.64206),
                     nom=c('Aranjuez', 'San Martin de la vega', 'Ruta de las vegas', 
                           'Mondejar', 'Universidad de Zaragoza, Zaragoza, España')
)

leaflet(data = puntos) %>% 
    addTiles() %>%
    setView(lng = puntos$lon[1], lat = puntos$lat[1] , zoom = 6) %>%
    addMarkers(~lon, ~lat, popup = ~as.character(nom), label = ~as.character(nom))
```

Ejemplo exportado a una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: @AdriánP.L., revisa mi última edición. Saludos.

Comment: GUAU!, funciona a la perfección. Muchas gracias Patricio

Comment: Hola Patricio Moracho, en el penúltimo mapa que me enseñaste, ¿Cómo puedo añadirle una escala? Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de escala? ¿Te refieres a los ejes? Si no me equivoco ahora está mostrando latitud y longitud.

Comment: Quería poner las medidas en grados sexasegimales en vez de longitud y latitud y el área que representa ¿Cómo podría hacerlo? muchas gracias de antemano